# Are there asymptotic expressions for multiple zetas $\small \zeta(s),\zeta(s,s),\zeta(s,s,s),\ldots$ where $\small s=1+\delta, \delta\to 0$?

Tags: reference-request, special-functions, zeta-functions, symmetric-polynomials

Playing around with *elementary symmetric functions* I tried to generalize that to infinite series and arrived at the well known concept of *MZV* ("multiple zeta values"). At the moment I'm only interested on that MZV, where all exponents are equal, and I compute that for the convergent cases by the rules of composition of the elementary symmetric functions by the according powersums and vice versa.
Meanwhile I've found a lot of material on MZV via google (mostly much "high-tech"), but very little on the simpler question of MZV with equal exponents (might be too introductory and there might not be too much interesting in it). Then I did not find anything about some asymptotic expression for the  $\small  \zeta(s),\zeta(s,s),\zeta(s,s,s),\ldots$ when $\small s=1+ \delta,  \delta \to 0 $ except the standard remark that they become singular.
Meanwhile I've tried to find some expression depending on the $\small \delta $ by numerical approximation using Pari/GP and also by the expression of the $\small \zeta(s) $ by a power series (and then develop the symbolic expression of the MZV's in that terms of power series), but do not yet have an conclusive general formulation.

Is there a simple answer for this or else some article around, which deals explicitely with that question?

---

[update after anon's comment] While the sequence of $\small \zeta(2),\zeta(2,2),\zeta(2,2,2),\ldots $ can be done nicely with the formulae for the elementary symmetric polynomials and using the convergent series $\small \zeta(1\cdot 2),\zeta(2\cdot 2),\zeta(3\cdot 2),\ldots$ at the place of the power-sums, clearly $\small \zeta(1),\zeta(1,1),\zeta(1,1,1) $ cannot be done although all except the first zetas used for this in the elementary-symmetric-polynomials formula: $\small \zeta(1 \cdot 1),\zeta(2 \cdot 1),\zeta(3 \cdot 1), \ldots $ are nonsingular. When I follow the idea of Ramanujan in his concept of zeta-regularization/-summation and set for the singularity $\zeta(1)$ the Euler-Mascheroni-constant $\small \gamma_0$ as first entry:$\small \gamma_0,\zeta(2 \cdot 1),\zeta(3 \cdot 1), \ldots $ at the place of the power-sums and determine the variants $\small \zeta^*(1),\zeta^*(1,1),\zeta^*(1,1,1),\ldots $ then the sum of all that MZV's adds just to 0 . ( If I use $\small \gamma_0-1,\zeta(2)-1,\zeta(3)-1, \ldots $ the MZV's sum up to $\small -\frac12 $, not much surprising) Just a nice finding meanwhile ...

Comment: We can write $e_n=P(p_1,\cdots,p_n)$ in elementary symmetric and power polynomials hence $$\zeta(\underbrace{s,\cdots,s}_n)=P\big(\zeta(s),\cdots,\zeta(ns)\big).$$ To get the asymptotic expansion of this up to $o(1)$, we would need to compute the Laurent expansion of $\zeta(s)$ up to around $(s-1)^{+n}$. Not to mention I don't think $P$ has a nice form to it. I doubt there's a simple answer to this.